# Adding many series efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, series

I have thousands of `pd.Series` items, and I just want to add them. They regard different time intervals, and I need to pad missing values with zeros. I tried

```
add_series = lambda a, b: a.add(b, fill_value=0).fillna(0)
result = reduce(add_series, all_my_items)
```

which takes more time than I would expect. Is there any way to speed this up significantly?

Comment: Isn't the `.fillna(0)` redundant after the `fill_value=0`?

Comment: I don't know if this helps your particular  case, but in general adding `Series`, appending to `DataFrame`s etc, is pretty slow. Are you able to merge the raw data, and then construct a single `Series` object at the end?

Comment: @ALollz: yes, in this case, I was also using it for adding frames.

Comment: @Batman: thanks, I suspected that, just wanted to know if I'm missing something obvious. I'll try to approach it the way you propose

Answer (score 2):

Using `concat`

```
pd.concat(all_my_items,axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. slightly faster, but just about 10%. Seems it's inherently slow procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can drop down to NumPy via [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) and [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). For performance, if possible you should avoid  regular Python methods when manipulating Pandas / NumPy objects.

The below solution assumes each series is aligned by index, i.e. the *k*<sup>th</sup> item of each series by position is comparable across series for each *k*.

```
np.random.seed(0)
m, n = 10**2, 10**4
S = [pd.Series(np.random.random(np.random.randint(0, m))) for _ in range(n)]

def combiner(arrs):
    n = max(map(len, arrs))
    L = [np.pad(i.values, (0, n-len(i)), 'constant') for i in arrs]
    return np.vstack(L).sum(0)

res1 = pd.concat(L, axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
res2 = pd.Series(combiner(S))
assert (res1 == res2).all()

%timeit pd.concat(L, axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)  # 2.63 s per loop
%timeit pd.Series(combiner(S))                      # 863 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks, but they regard different time intervals. might not even have the same size.

Comment: @blue_note, See update, you can pad your arrays with NumPy too to make them the same size. I'm seeing a ~3x improvement for specific parameters.

Comment: @blue_note if you are relying on the index alignment behavior of pandas, you are effectively doing a join with each addition. That is far more expensive than just adding across vectors.

Comment: @shadowtalker, Yes, I am relying on alignment of indices. It's not clear if that's a sticking point with OP's use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.concat` but with `axis=0` and then `groupby` on `level=0` such as:

```
pd.concat(all_my_items,axis=0).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

With `all_my_items` containing 1000 `pd.Series` of different lengths (e.g. between 2000 and 2500) and different time intervals such as:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
n = 1000 #number of series
#lengths of the series
len_ser = np.random.randint(2000, 2500, n)
# to pick a random start date 
list_date = pd.date_range(start = pd.to_datetime('1980-01-01'), periods=15000).tolist()
# generate the list of pd.Series
all_my_items = [pd.Series(range(len_ser[i]), 
                          index=pd.date_range(start=list_date[np.random.randint(0,15000,1)[0]], 
                                              periods=len_ser[i])) 
               for i in range(n)]

# Wen's solution
%timeit pd.concat(all_my_items,axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1) #1.47 s ± 138 ms per loop
#this solution
%timeit pd.concat(all_my_items,axis=0).groupby(level=0).sum() #270 ms ± 11.3 ms

#verify same result
print (pd.concat(all_my_items,axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1) == 
       pd.concat(all_my_items,axis=0).groupby(level=0).sum()).all()) #True
```

So the result is the same and the operation is faster